# Postman and POST request

Tags: post, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, postman

I have the following web api methods:

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("GetUserStatus")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetUserStatus()
    {

    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Send")]
    public HttpResponseMessage Send(string usernameTo, string message)
    {

    }
```

when I call a GET request - it works fine. But when I try to send a POST request - I get an error:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:11015/api/Chat/Send'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No action was found on the controller 'ChatApi' that matches the request."
}
```

and counter of failure calls for that method is incremented. Why so?
I try the following way:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong but I think the problem is that you are packaging your parameters as a single object in Postman. You can try setting `usernameTo` and `message` as Params in the Postman UI *OR* change the input of your `Send` method to a single object that contains `usernameTo` and `message` as properties/fields (don't forget to match the casing). I prefer the latter. Something like this:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Send")]
public HttpResponseMessage Send(MessageDetails details)
{

}

public class MessageDetails
{
    public string usernameTo { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Your anser corrects the problem but it's not a Postman problem, Web Api can take just one parameter that will be deserialized from the body.

Comment: You are correct, I didn't mean to imply it was specifically Postman-related. I called it out because that's the method used in the original question.